# A Question From Shiryaev

Tags: probability-theory

I was studying about $\lambda$-systems from Shiryaev where I countered the following statement about equivalence of conditions for defining a $\lambda$-system.
[image]

I can check the equivalence of the second set of conditions given the first. However, going the other way, I am not able to show condition $(\lambda_{b})$ given conditions $(\lambda_{a}), (\lambda'_{b})$ and $(\lambda'_{c})$.

Can someone please provide a hint on how to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $A,B \in \mathscr{L}$ and $A \subseteq B$, then can you show (In my notation, $B^c$ is the complement of $B$)

a) $B^c \in \mathscr{L}$

b)$B^c\bigcup A  \in \mathscr{L}$ (Since $A\subseteq B \iff A\cap B^c = \phi$).

c)$B^c\bigcup A = (B\setminus A)^c$

Comment: Can you explain this $A\subseteq B \iff A\cap B^c = \phi$?

Comment: You can see it easily via venn diagrams. Or formally $A=(A\cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c)$. Note that the two are disjoint. Since $A \subseteq B$ implies $A \cap B = A$, what can you say about $A\cap B^c$ ?

Comment: Got it, thanks. I was complementing the wrong set earlier.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I got the argument...